# Why returning a member variable using "this" pointer is not allowed, but setting a member variable using "this" is allowed?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, this, intellisense

Here's the header file code:

```
#ifndef __MANAGER_H__PROJECT_A__
#define __MANAGER_H__PROJECT_A__

#include <string>

class Manager {
private:
    std::string type;
    bool isStarted;
protected:
    void setType(std::string type);
public:
    Manager();
    virtual ~Manager();

    //Get type identifier
    std::string getType();

    //Startup manager. 0: Startup ok. Any #: Not ok.
    virtual int startUp();

    //Shutdown manager. 
    virtual void shutDown();

    //True: startUp executed ok. False, otherwise.
    bool isStarted() const;
};

#endif
```

The code below shows the error as "A pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function".

```
bool Manager::isStarted() const {
    return this->isStarted;        //<----   ERROR.
}
```

And should be changed to this.

```
bool Manager::isStarted() const {
    return Manager::isStarted;     //<----   Correct.
}
```

So why is this acceptable?

```
void Manager::setType(std::string type){
    this->type = type;             //<----   Correct.
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is allowed. The error is unrelated: you are using the wrong variable name.

Comment: Or, more specifically, you've aliased ``isStarted`` to be the name of a method in the class, and thus ``this->isStarted`` is attempting to return a pointer to the member-method ``Manager::isStarted`` rather than some boolean value ``isStarted``. So your code that doesn't work doesn't work because it's not doing what you think it's doing, and your code that does work works because it's not doing what you think it's doing, because the returned pointer can be implicitly cast as a ``bool``.

Comment: I'm stupid. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: For those who are downvoting, please stop. I just want to move on, and reflect upon this mistake. Instead, I would like to ask of you to vote it closed. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically, you've aliased `isStarted` to be the name of a method in the class, and thus `this->isStarted` is attempting to return a pointer to the member-method `Manager::isStarted` rather than some boolean value `isStarted`.

So your code that doesn't work doesn't work because it's not doing what you think it's doing. And your code that does work works because it's also not doing what you think it's doing; the returned pointer can be implicitly cast as a `bool` (and will always be equal to `true`), so you don't get a wrong return type error.

Comment: I'm stupid. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for letting me know. I deserve it.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 It's ok, happens to the best of us. Implicit conversions allowing something to happen that isn't the programmer's intention are a source of endless bugs in C++ code. Don't feel too bad.

Comment: I feel bad not because of the error, rather the question is now a downvote magnet. I can't delete it, so my best hope is for someone else to mark it as closed. I do not want to attract any more downvotes, even if I deserve it. I just wanted to move on.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I'm actually surprised it's getting as many down votes as it is. It's a legitimate question, and you certainly provided a MCVE. At worst people should've been voting for close do to typo, not down voting.

Answer (score 2):

You are messing up with names!!

`isStarted` is the name of a member function. Your first example is therefore wrong.

In the second, you are converting the address of `isStarted` to a bool, and then you return it (it will always return true!!)

In the third, you use `this` to properly distiguish between the member variable `type` and the formal variable `type`.